# Is this projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

What we know about projection matrices:

$A^T=A $

$A=A^2 $

I want to prove that $(I-A)^T $is also projection matrix :

My solution:

$(I-A)^T =I-A^T=I-A=I-A^2$

we can see that $ I-A=I-A^2 => 0=A-A^2$,
$A^2=A$ then $A-A=0$

Does it look correct?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You haven't proven that $(I-A)^2=I-A$.

Comment: Note that $(I-A)^T = I^T-A^T = I - A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You need to prove that
$$\left((I-A)^T\right)^T = (I-A)^T, \quad \left((I-A)^T\right)^2 = (I-A)^T.$$

Comment: $((I-A)^T)^T =(I^T-A^T)^T=(I-A)^T$  Maybe it is ok

Comment: @BlackSwan_22 That's it. Now the other one.

Comment: $(I−A^T)^2=(I−A)^T(I−A)^T=((I−A)(I−A))^T=(I−2A+A^2)^T=(I−A)^T$

Comment: @BlackSwan_22 The first one should be $\left((I-A)^T\right)^2$ but yes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by *"we can see that $ I-A=I-A^2 => 0=A-A^2$
$A^2=A$ then $A-A=0$"*.

However

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(I - A^T\right)^2 & = (I-A)^T(I-A)^T\\
&=\left((I-A)(I-A)\right)^T\\
&= (I-2A + A^2)^T\\
&=(I-A)^T
\end{aligned}$$

So $(I-A)^T$ which satisfies the two required identities to be a projection is indeed a projection.